# How to make mdc.Table extand the settings in sap.m.ListBase? SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm new in SAP and trying to build a backend with SAPUI5.

Now, I have a table that refers to the [Sample: Table with FilterBar and JSON model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.mdc/sample/sap.ui.mdc.demokit.sample.TableFilterBarJson), however, it seems not able to support the properties of `sap.m.ListBase`.

For example, I'd like to make it load the data with `growingScrollToLoad` mode instead of showing the "More" button.
[image]

Could someone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The mdc.Table should support a [growingMode](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.mdc.enums.TableGrowingMode)

sap.ui.mdc.enums.TableGrowingMode.Scroll should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply very much! However, I'm not familiar with SAP... Could you please kindly show me how to use the API "TableGrowingMode.Scroll", I have tried to add it as an attribute in and under "mdc:Table", but it seems not to work like that.